# Split parse text file in java

Tags: java, file, parsing, split

So basically I could read the text file, using BUFFERED READER.
After that I Should SPLIT and PARSE it, at this point, I am facing a problem.

> Output is:
>   5   2   9
>   1   7   3
>   9   2   10
>   11  6   3
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "F:\Gephi\number.txt"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at javaapplication17.JavaApplication17.main(JavaApplication17.java:42)
>   C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

MY CODE IS

```
package javaapplication17;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;




public class JavaApplication17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String count = "F:\\Gephi\\number.txt";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(count))) 
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        // What is the Problem in this part? //

        String[] abc = count.split("/t");
        int[] intArray = new int[abc.length];

        for (int i=0; i<abc.length; i++)

        {

        String numberAsString = abc[i];
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);


        }

        System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intArray.length);

        System.out.println("The integers are:");
        for (int number : intArray)

        {

        System.out.println(number);

        }






    }
}
```

My text file looks like this

```
5   6   7
5   2   9
1   7   3
9   2   10
11  6   3
```

Comment: Try `Integer.parseInt(numberAsString.trim());`

Comment: how do you want split `count` ? this `String[] abc = count.split("/t");`

Comment: It should be like this `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line += line;
            }` and then use `String[] abc = line.split("/t");`

Comment: @HadiJ I tried that sir, but still stuck :(

Comment: `String numbers = "",line;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(count)))
        {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                numbers+=line;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }`

Comment: and `String[] abc = numbers.split("(?<=.)");
        int[] intArray = new int[abc.length];
        for (int i=0; i<abc.length; i++)

        {
            String numberAsString = abc[i];
            if (!numberAsString.equals(""))
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString.trim());
        }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `count` is a String that contains the value `"F:\\Gephi\\number.txt"`. This does not give you the number of rows/columns in the file.

```
String[] abc = count.split("/t");  // <------ This won't work
```

So when you do

```
int[] intArray = new int[abc.length];
```

you are creating an array with size of `abc` that is split by `\t` which is incorrect.

---

To solve you issue you can change the `try-catch` block to the following :

```
int countOfNum = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(count))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] currLine = line.split("\t");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currLine));
        countOfNum = countOfNum + currLine.length;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Total count of numbers : " +countOfNum);
```

- In the above solution we split each line into the variable `currLine`
- Next using the `Arrays.toString()` we print out the values
- Now using the variable `countOfNum` we find the total number of
  elements in the file.

Comment: Ah, I see! What could be the probable solution then? And thank you so much for the editing help! :)

Comment: No issues. Also what exactly are you trying to do after reading the file? Do you just want to count and display the integers only? Why do you need an array here specifically?

Comment: Firstly read, then count, then split and parse them! Basically 4 things